# No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument

Tags: c#

Making a mod for a game, and I'm trying to get the name of the character always, when it spawns, Matt.

However, this didn't go well for me. Despite the countless problems I fixed by myself, I can't find a way around this error:

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument

Here is the code:

```
switch (WorldGen.genRand.Next(0))
{
    case 0:
        return ToString("Matt");
}
```

Comment: The default `ToString()` from `object` doesn't have overloads. You need to just `return "Matt"`.

Comment: ToString needs an type to convert to a string, like `int.ToString()`

Comment: There's no such `int.ToString()` directly. It should be `Convert.ToString(intvariable)` or `intvariable.ToString()`. Now that `string` to `bool` conversion is invalid, check what type your method returns.

Comment: Please show us the complete code

Comment: please post the method in which the code is situated  ( or at least the signature) and the line where you intend to use it

Comment: The code you have posted will not compile. ToString requires an instance. It is not static.

Comment: @CodingYoshi and @Ben ToString can refer to the instance `this.`. So it would be possible to call it inside a method inside a class

Comment: @mongzhu yes if the class has overridden it.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, please use the edit button below your post or [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45230140/edit) to add further information to your post. Up to now it is likely to be closed as unclear because of the lack of essential information to be able to help you.

Comment: @CodingYoshi not necessarily, every object inherits this method automatically, so you would be able to call just `ToString()`, but I agree on the point that you cannot simply shove a string as parameter into it, as the example posted by OP proves

Comment: @mongzhu yes like i said it is not static.

Answer (score 1):

`ToString` is a `virtual` method of `Object` class. which can be used to convert a type to string. So the way you have tried to use is not correct. Change you code to this. Also the "Matt" is already in string format so you need not to convert that. If your method returns string type then you should use

```
switch (WorldGen.genRand.Next(0))
{
    case 0:
        return "Matt";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you would also explain why this helps, your answer would be of more value to OP.

Answer (score 0):

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument

The message is clear in stating that `ToString` does not take any arguments. You are probably trying to do something similar to this(Please note the comments in code below):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sc = new SomeClass();
        sc.ToString(); // works
        // does not work because SomeClass does not have a ToString method
        /// which takes one parameter
        sc.ToString("whatever");
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
}
```

In the code above, `SomeClass` does not have a `ToString` method but by default all classes derive the `Object` class which has a `ToString()` method. Therefore, calling `ToString()` (without any arguments) will work because that method is inherited from `Object`. However, calling `ToString("WithArgument")` will not work and result in the exception you are getting. If you just want to return `Matt` or any other string, simply do this:

```
return "Matt"; // or anything else
```